# I edited my question. How do I get it back?

Tags: support, reopen-request, closed-questions, editing, offtopic

Some other user edited my question and then it got closed. I edited it back, along with some other changes, to make it become more to my original intent.

[Is there a minimum number of candidates that need to be interviewed before a decision is made?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/177649/is-there-a-minimum-number-of-candidates-that-need-to-be-interviewed-before-a-dec)

Comment: You got some great answers. Why worry that it's closed now? Currently you seem to be seeking a magic number. Obviously, there is no such number across companies. Any number would be company-specific. Most companies don't have a minimum. As currently constructed, your question reads only like a complaint, with an unanswerable question tacked on.

Comment: Your question is no longer accepting new answers, but it’s scored high enough that not going to be deleted. What do you hope will happen if it’s reopened? Is there something unsatisfactory about the answer you accepted?

Comment: I echo a bit of what others have said. You already got 100+ vote answers... you even accepted one, which means you got your solution... I see it's a good post... what do you hope to get with opening it again?

Answer (score 4):

It's a pity this question is closed, because even if the the wrong question is posed, there are a few great answers that the community may find interesting.

I am not satisfied with the mentality of "you got your answer, what more do you want?". Content serves more users than just the person who posed the OP. It's great that users want to improve their content, even if they have answers to their question.

I think the "Accepted Answer" functionality is next to useless on this Stack, so I don't think it should have any bearing on if a question is closed.

Comment: Closed questions aren't deleted if they have upvoted answers. The answers aren't going to disappear because the question is closed. The only reason to leave a question open would be to attract more answers, so the question "What kind of additional answers are you hoping to receive when your question is reopened?" helps to understand whether there is a failing in the current answers, or whether the author has confused "closing" with a prelude to deletion.

Comment: @ColleenV `The only reason to leave a question open would be to attract more answers` since when do  popular questions with good answers get closed when the OP accepts an answer? I've seen moderators delete highly upvoted questions that had attracted over 15 answers, and once an answer that earned over 50 upvotes was deleted by a mod on EL&U albeit many moons ago. Furthermore it is not true that upvoted but closed questions with upvoted answers are immune from deletion. They are immune from being deleted by the *system* but not by human mods.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Reopening the question does nothing to protect it from moderator action.